# XML to CSV formatting

Tags: python, xml, csv, argparse

I have a program that converts csv to xml to csv. However, when i am converting it back to csv, the formatting has gone wrong. Originally the csv file is like so:

```
x1    y1    z1    x2    y2    z2    cost
 1     2     3     4     5     6       7
```

and so on and so forth. This data is also represented using excel.
I then convert this to xml like so:

```
<Solution version="1.0">
  <DrillHoles total_holes="238">
    <description>
      <hole hole_id="1">
        <collar>1, 2, 3</collar>
        <toe>4, 5, 6</toe>
        <cost>7</cost>
      </hole>
```

*note that is only one part of the whole thing but it is enough for this example.
SO when i convert this back into csv format it appears to be like this:

```
 x1    y1     z1    x2    y2    z2    cost
123                 456               7
```

where x1y1z1x2y2z2cost are jumbled up in one column in excel . Also this is represented in a excel.

Here is my code for generating xml:

```
def generate_xml(reader,outfile):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)        
    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    i = 1
    for row in reader.next():
        x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
        if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
            current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

            collar = SubElement(current_group,'collar')
            toe = SubElement(current_group,'toe')
            cost1 = SubElement(current_group,'cost')
            collar.text = ', '.join((x1,y1,z1))
            toe.text = ', '.join((x2,y2,z2))
            cost1.text = cost
        i+=1
    head.set('total_holes', '%s'%i)
    indent.indent(root)
    tree.write(outfile)
```

generating csv:
    def generate_csv(root, outfile):
        with open(outfile, 'w') as file_:

```
        writer = csv.writer(file_, delimiter="\t")
        writer.writerow(['x1'] + ['y1'] + ['z1'] + ['x2'] + ['y2'] + ['z2'] + ['cost'])
        for a in zip(root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/collar"),
                 root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/toe"),
                 root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/cost")):
            writer.writerow([x.text for x in a])
```

please help thanks
edit: i think i might need multiple delimiters but i do not know how to incorporate that into this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the split, which is symmetric to the join((x1,y1,z1)) you make when you generate xml. Something like this:

```
for a in zip(root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/collar"),
         root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/toe"),
         root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/cost")):
    collars, toes, cost = a
    collars = [x.strip() for x in collars.text.split(',')]
    toes = [x.strip() for x in toes.text.split(',')]
    cost = [cost.text]
    writer.writerow(collars + toes + cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use an excel dialect with the csv writer class, so excel would detect delimiters correctly:

try to change line:

writer = csv.writer(file_, delimiter="\t")

to this line:

writer = csv.writer(file_, dialect='excel')

but if you need tab as delimiter, you can try to trim around settings when you import csv file in excel